# Getting coordinate grid per country

Tags: python, coordinates, vector-grid

I need a coordinate grid per country, 0.08 degrees (?) apart from each other.
It looks like this:

[image]

I would want the coordinates of the intersections.
Instead of a perfect rectangle, I would want it to stop at the border of a specific country. Is there any way I can get an array of coordinates this way?

I have made a Python script myself which just makes the rectangle bigger than the country itself, but this isn't the best way.

```
def get_coords(top_left, bottom_right):

coord = [top_left[0], top_left[1]]
lat = top_left[0]
lon = top_left[1]
coord = [lat, lon]
coords = []
while True:
    index = 0
    if lat > bottom_right[0]:
        lat = coord[0] - 0.08
    else:
        if lon < bottom_right[1]:
            lon = coord[1] + 0.08
            lat = top_left[0]
        else:
            break

    coord = [lat, lon]
    coords.append(coord)
    
return coords
```

Any tips or solutions?

Comment: What GIS software are you using?  What does your code attempt look like?

Comment: Oh wait, maybe I posted in the wrong stackexchange. I thought this was just for general geographical questions, not a particular software. Is this still relevant?

Comment: We have a [tag:gis-principle] tag for theoretical questions but for those no software should be mentioned or sought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard approach to this problem is to first create a grid for the extent and then eliminate the grid geometries which do not intersect with the geometry of the country. You can use any gis software package, as the `intersects` and `contains` conditions are common use cases. `Shapely` library could be useful for this.

Example (note I changed your `[lat, lon]` format to `[lon, lat]`:

```
from shapely.geometry import MultiPolygon, Polygon, box, MultiPoint, Point
from shapely import wkt

def get_geometries(top_left, bottom_right, spacing=0.08):
    polygons = []
    points = []
    xmin = top_left[0]
    xmax = bottom_right[0]
    ymax = top_left[1]
    y = bottom_right[1]
    i = -1
    while True:
        if y > ymax:
            break
        x = xmin

        while True:
            if x > xmax:
                break
            
            #components for polygon grid
            polygon = box(x, y, x+spacing, y+spacing)
            polygons.append(polygon)

            #components for point grid
            point = Point(x, y)
            points.append(point)
            i = i + 1
            x = x + spacing

        y = y + spacing
    return polygons, points

polygons, points = get_geometries((14, 54), (24, 49), 0.5)

##country_geom is a shapely polygon with country boundaries
country_geom = wkt.loads('POLYGON((17.564247434051406 54.446991320181255,16.311806027801406 54.061910892199705,15.575722043426405 53.37933926382691,15.377968137176405 52.79871812523439,15.575722043426405 51.98076121960815,15.619667355926405 51.15448239676194,16.696327512176406 50.94037053252475,17.871864621551406 50.47422670556861,18.761757199676406 50.27102433369101,21.54709245171919 50.3018762188395,22.28317643609419 50.31590902034586,23.19504167046919 51.019189209157204,22.65671159234419 52.08481472438036,22.79953385796919 52.86108007657073,22.48237015280161 53.76537437170607,22.24067093405161 54.11458487224089,20.402314605750536 54.24318115411181,18.908173980750536 54.09526092933704,18.007295074500536 54.396969300395,17.564247434051406 54.446991320181255))')

intersecting_polygons = []
intersecting_points = []
for polygon in polygons:
    if polygon.intersects(country_geom):
        intersecting_polygons.append(polygon)

for point in points:
    if country_geom.contains(point):
        intersecting_points.append(point)

polygon_grid = MultiPolygon(intersecting_polygons)
point_grid = MultiPoint(intersecting_points)

#grids are shapely geometries. You can output them as WKT format
print(point_grid.wkt)
print(polygon_grid.wkt)
```

First grid:

[image]

Fake country boundaries (didn't want to bother with finding the actual ones so I drew something on the map):

[image]

Result:

[image]

Result (polygon version):

[image]

Comment: Damn, this is exactly what I need! Thank you so much!

Comment: Also, do you know where to get the actual country borders? It doesn't need to very precise, a polygon like your example will do just fine :)

Comment: Here for example: https://hub.arcgis.com/datasets/a21fdb46d23e4ef896f31475217cbb08_1

Comment: You will probably need to play around with some GIS software to extract the boundaries (they are in SHP format). If you encounter new problems, make a new question. If you need only approximate boundaries, then you can check out https://arthur-e.github.io/Wicket/sandbox-gmaps3.html, draw the boundaries yourself and paste the wkt polygon in the code I gave you.

Comment: Finally, please accept the answer if it was useful :)

Comment: Thank you for all the help! I will :)